# Update the content of a div every so often

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that updates the contents of a div every 5 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(sensor,5000);
});

function sensor(){
$("#ex2").load("http://localhost:8050/ss2");
}
</script>
```

The content is a table that shows the data of a database and it is constantly updated, the information is updated but at the moment these updates start it brings me the whole page inside the div in this way:

[image: Image (1) of the table before updating]

[image: Image (2) after it is updated]

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: This isn't a solution, but I would suggest structuring your 5 second delay to start after a successful request (`.load` has a callback function that can be used for this) Rather than running every 5 seconds regardless (Which could lead to multiple requests being active simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for what I can see `http://localhost:8050/ss2` is also the URL of your page to visit? You should create another page that only gives you the html of the table, then you can replace the original contents.

Or you should extract the table html from the data you have (not sure what it's code is to be able do this for you). Then create a node from that text and add it to you r DOM